# Springer GTM Reprints in China?

Tags: textbook-recommendation, books, journals

I apologise if this is not the sort of question appropriate for MO; it does however seem that mathematicians are the most likely to know the answer:

Many of the Chinese mathematicians and graduate students at my university have softcover copies of some of the older Springer GTMs, usually printed on thin paper with Chinese characters on the front cover, but with the actual text in English. Someone said that they can be bought quite cheaply in China and are legitimate `Chinese Reprints' of the original books. Internet searches on both Google and the Springer website turn up nothing, however, so I presume the origin of these books is somewhat dubious:

Does someone know the actual status of these books and has anyone purchased one outside of China?

Comment: Such things have existed since at least the 1980s: the pricing of books in India and China "had to" make them vastly cheaper, given currency exchange and local economic conditions), or Springer (et al) could not sell any at all. No, they did not sell anything at a loss, or... why bother? The point is that the "Western" market could then (and still now) bear much bigger mark-ups (over cost of production), and has precedents for believing that it's ok, or ... something.

Comment: My understanding is that they are legitimate reprints of Springer books, but they cannot be sold outside of PRC for copyright reasons. On my visit to Shanghai I bought a bag of such GTMs in a local bookshop :-)

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, I'm not sure that the copyright thang is really true, although I've heard it myself. By this point, I think it's that <large international corporation> wants to persuade people to not disrupt it's practices... not illegal practices, but, um, profitable-unless-disrupted. I've had a textbook of mine (foolishly giving away the copyright in the 90s...) translated and printed in Chinese in China, and, amazingly, that version only costs maybe a buck or two, while the U.S. version cost nearly 100 bux. "Go figger..."

Comment: There have been high profile court cases about importing Chinese printings into USA (for resale).  Unfortunately, I do not recall the results. Until DMCA, though, the basic rule was that if you legally came to own a book, then that book was yours, and you could do whatever you wanted with it physically, although you could not, by default, produce copies.

Comment: Well, it's very usual to see these "Not for sale in ..." printed in bold on first pages of textbooks. E.g. there are lots of such books on sale in Singapore at a big discount (e.g. "baby Rudin" for 12$US).

Comment: When I was in Beijing I found a bookstore near my hotel with a lot of these Springer books (Chinese writing added to front cover, English unchanged). It is totally legit. The copy of Griffiths & Harris I saw had the table of contents in Chinese, but other English math books did not translate that part. When I returned to the US I was advised by several Chinese people that the books easily fall apart under regular use, so I have treated mine extra carefully.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, the line is not "Not for sale in..." but rather "... for sale in the Mainland China only and not for export therefrom." Hmm, not surprised it has an English error, like the chopstick instructions.

Comment: @KConrad How do you know they are totally legit?  My impression is that some books are and some aren't.  I've bought things like CDs from Chinese stores that afterwards seemed to be illegal copies.

Comment: I've had a number of my Springer books published in China just as several people have described. This is done via some sort of agreement that Springer has with some Chinese publisher, I guess. They do indeed appear to be cheaply constructed (as per Keith's comment) and contain the "for sale...only" as he says. So they are certainly being legally published in China. I get a few free copies, and there is actually a very small royalty payment, on the order of a few cents per copy, which Springer keeps half of and gives the other half to the author. OTOH, no one ...

Comment: ...in their right mind publishes books at this level with the idea of making large sums of money. One wants them widely distributed and used (and hopefully appreciated) by students and colleagues. Of course, it is also a lot of work writing a book, so I'm not going to object to receiving a couple of dollars for each one sold in the US or Europe.

Comment: Just to add to the general line of comments: my GTM book with Chris Godsil has a Chinese version, produced by Springer, with Chinese text on the outside and the original text on thin low-quality paper on the inside. Of course this does not mean that most, or even any, others are legitimate.

Comment: I have bought books on the internet from used books stores, and received such, apparently new, yellow books with chinese signs of them. Must be an extra income source for chinese students ...

Comment: So, if this is an accurate description of the situation, @kjetilbhalvorsen, the original student seller (and to a much lesser extent, all the later sellers) are in effect stealing from the authors the legitimate fruits of their labor.

Comment: @KConrad I meant non-Springer books. Strangely enough Springer does not have any discounted reprints in Singapore.

Answer (score 15):

They are legitimate editions, published by an agreement with *China Science Press*. They are for sale in China only. These reprints are done not only for GTMs but also many other maths books. See the enclosed photoes for an example. In this case the price is 98 yuan in China.

[image: Kozlov: Combinatorial Algebraic Topology]

[image: Copyright page of the book by Kozlov]